# ListBox Visibility property doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, visibility

I have a problem with change dynamically Visivility property of Listbox in wpf. After clicking button, property change but I have to double-click to refresh it. So after one click, nothing change. How can I do this?

```
<ListBox Visibility="Collapsed" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="listBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
</ListBox>

private void btListBoxAction_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) {
        listBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else {
        listBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

}

Comment: What have you done so far?Update your question with your attempted code

Comment: I'm using RibbonMenuButton. Im able to handle click event only in this way.

Comment: As per your code it will work absolutely fine.

Comment: It's not working. I have to always double click ;/

Comment: Check the properties of your RibbonMenuButton.Check the click  events.